# Android service freeze Activity

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to make an android service communicating with an external device. It's well working but my UI is completly freeze until the service end his work.

Here is my service code :

```
    //That method is execute the first and only the first time the service is bind
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d("Service", "Creating service");

    buildNotificationBarControls(radioStatus);
}

//this one is called on each bind
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Service", "in onBind");

    return mBinder;
}
```

here my service connection (registercallback register the callback that manage communication between service and activity and DeviceManager communicate with the external device and send signal with previous callbacks :

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        binder = GetDeviceServiceInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
        mBound = true;      

        try {
            Log.d("Debug", "on connection try");
            binder.registerCallback(mCallback);

            binder.DeviceManager();

        } catch (RemoteException e) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBound = false; 
        binder = null;
    }
};
```

and I bind my service into the onResume with :

```
    getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GetDeviceService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_ALLOW_OOM_MANAGEMENT);
```

at your disposal,

Comment: Try to do your service code in an Async task

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation 
`A service runs in the main thread of the application that hosts it, by default`. 
So try to start your service in a thread or AsyncTask() to make it run in another thread.

Comment: Do you mean something like this
`   Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
     getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GetDeviceService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
    };
    t.start();`

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Comment: I make that call in my on resume but doesn't solve the freeze issu

Answer (score 0):

Normal services run in mainn UI thread by default. You should either create a thread inside service or use IntentService instead. IntentService runs in its own thread.

Comment: can i still use my binder and keep my service bounded with intentService?

Comment: No. You should use IntentService and ResultReceiver/Messenger/LocalbroadcastManager pattern for data passing. Visit this http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/05/intentservice-providing-data-back-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by launching my service operation in different threads